# ASP.NET Razor like WYSIWYG Browser Editor

Tags: email, templates, razor, wysiwyg

We have been using asp.net mvc razor technology as a template engine to allow the user to develop razor scripts on the client. we are using this for email template engine.

You can see example at Ricks blog on that
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Dec/27/Hosting-the-Razor-Engine-for-Templating-in-NonWeb-Applications

I was wondering if anyone know of a WYSIWYG style editor for the client browser that we can use instead of just a TextArea? Something similar to Visual Studio editor that show razor syntax etc..

Thanks,
Noam

Comment: did you find anything useful for this?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an interesting  application. I don't think there's an editor that supports the Razor syntax, but you can probably modify an existing client-side rich HTML editor to fit your needs. Here are some listed: http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors

Answer (score 0):

Following are the links to MVC HTML editor that you might already know:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx

http://mvccontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

http://richtexteditor.com/mvc/

Comment: All three links are gone, or show 404 errors.